# Extending XBRL Calculation Networks

Tags: xbrl

When a filing agency allows company-specific taxonomy extensions, do the relations in the calculation networks of the base taxonomy remain binding? The specific case that I have in mind is this:

Given a base taxonomy with the concepts C1, C2 and CTotal and a calculation network that defines CTotal = C1 + C2.
A company-specific extension taxonomy introduces a new concept C3 as a sibling of C1 and C2, and alters the calculation network to become CTotal = C1 + C2 + C3.

XBRL-wise, everything is valid. The question is whether the filing agency will accept such a filing. Are filers allowed to change calculation networks in such a way that the relations in the base taxonomy become invalid?

Comment: There is no generic answer to this. It depends fully on who is collecting the data and what their requirements are. This is usually defined in a filers manual or similar documentation. You need to ask the filing agency what they accept.

Comment: I kind of suspected that. Many thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the regulator you are filing with.  If this is the US SEC, not only is it permitted but is expected.  Any filing agent supporting SEC registrants would be able to handle this.

Louis